# Convert real number from 2 till 16 without converting to decimal bases

Tags: python, python-3.x, converters, radix

I got the following problems but I'm not able to figure it out how to do it, is it possible someone can help me?

Define 1 function num = b−any 2 b−any (num1 , b−in, b−out)
which receives 1 real number num1, your base b−in and the base of conversion b−out than shows
the result on the requested base (num on the base b−out)

From the previous example, show the converted number on floating point.

The bigger problem is it to change without pre-existing function that belongs on the numpy, the sum I can do it, but the thing that confused me it was how to use the hornet model on this.

Make the product from 2 distinct numbers that belongs on the same base.

In example, first, 1110, on base 2, I want to convert to any bases between 2~16 without converting to base 10. I deals with the hornet method however didn't get how to put in a function.

Comment: please provide the example in the question.

Comment: Either you introduced some errors, copying your homework problem into this question, or your course teacher put as much effort into writing it as you did into trying to solve it. [How to ask homework questions on StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)